# Infinite loop? Any suggestions?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, while-loop, syntax

I cannot progress through the program when entering a name, I have to enter "Q". Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
empName = prompt("Enter employee's name or Q to quit: ");

    while (empName != "Q") {
      empTot = 0;
    
      for (var i = 0; /  i < 5;  i++) {
        prompt("Enter the amount of day " + (i + 1) + ": ");
    
    }
    document.write(empName + ": total is " + empTot);
```

Full program is here:
https://repl.it/@IAdams6748/Frozen-Rainbow-Emp#script.js

Comment: [Learn how to format your code so that you can get help faster here on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 1):

you have a "/" in you for.

try

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using a while loop, unless you know what you're doing, because of the possibility to create an infinite loop.

Instead, use a if statement to check if the input was a "Q". For the sake of usability, I made the possibility to quit case insensitive.

You had a typo in your for loop, by having `/` in it, and you never added empTot together with the answer from the prompt. I wrapped the prompted in a parseInt and added a default value by adding  `|| 0` at the end.

You also never declared new variables with `var`. You should always do that when declaring variables, or some browser will not understand where the variable is coming from.

```js
var empName = prompt("Enter employee's name or Q to quit: ");

if (empName && empName.toLowerCase() != "q") {
  var empTot = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    empTot += parseInt(prompt("Enter the amount of day " + (i + 1) + ": ")) || 0;
  }
  
  document.write(empName + ": total is " + empTot);
}
```

Comment: For the sake of this assignment, I have to use the while statement. I have to covert pseudocode into Javascript. I am just unsure why I have to enter "Q" to progress into the program. It will not accept anything else.

Comment: So the assignment is "ask for the number of days at most five times or until the user types "q"?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing } for your while loop